# change default installation location salt stack windows minion

Tags: windows, salt-stack

Is it possible to change the default installation location for salt stack on windows? Instead of c:\salt I would like to specify a different location. I am using the silent installer BTW

Comment: If it is possible there [is documentation missing](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/installation/windows.html#silent-installer-options)

Comment: yep. The documentation does not state it.